# Padding error in Encrypt RSA PKCS1_OAEP in Python

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, padding, pycryptodome

I'm working with Python and PyCryptodome at the last version. I Use a Publick key, decode to base64 and pass to RSA, then encrypt some message and save the encrypted result witj PKCS1_OAEP¨.
My problem is that I can't decrypt the message using the private key, because of a padding error.
I have some encrypted results from before a massive updating of libraries and those messages works, I can decrypt those files.
The files that works are 512 bytes, but the encrypted messages I got are rounding between 214~380 bytes, with no fixed size, i don't know why.

My code is:

```
txt = "hello"
pubkey = see below
keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)
publickey = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(publickey)
encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(bytes(txt, "utf-8"))
f = open("file.encrypted", "wb")
f.write(encrypted)
f.flush()
f.close()
```

Then to decrypt I use in console:

```
openssl rsautl -oaep -decrypt -inkey  claveprivada.pem -in file.encrypted -out key.txt
```

And got the following error:

```
RSA operation error
44276:error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error:../openssl-1.1.1s/crypto/rsa/rsa_oaep.c:262:
44276:error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed:../openssl-1.1.1s/crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:491:
```

The public key is:

```
pubkey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxfLqdKTtAFwh8lPf/sjE6N3rPZqyjHNYglGQRPJ6sHHs0Ciw18v8R4eVEIwdGslFDvg3usP1PMQrW9Nyy16Sz4T5lUyPTZFgvQ0xyB1HH9gqyprxV7Rcdb5iRLj3HuUG8Bg/4mWvp5I69GpZcpPFwm0T7Y8Np1ouErf6f+Yp6c4X0JQ5Cm8EIGmom0mRw93uouYXZ+P8WMd/EEdgRl8vJpgkewt99lm5SPsW3742bgfnsT38Z2vJMziXtVIPVsdH5yKGe0arAYIY6UHC+JnOS/KjBZ609Px5Z785ZrppXiVEX0K4e294S5xhpzPuNLTAsYPfLWDjwaLZGN8hGvFSCwIDAQAB"
```

The private key (for testing purposes) is

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Private and public key are not related (the modulus of the private key is not the same as that of the public key).

Comment: LOL That was the error XD, I changed the public key, now it works, thanks X'D